# Jquery validate plugin check for at least 1 letter and 1 number

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I'll admit I'm a total noob when it comes to regex. I'm trying to write a custom validation method for the jquery validate plugin. I'm trying to check if an input has at least 1 number and 1 letter in it.

This is what I've come up with at the moment, but it doesn't work. Would really appreciate some help please.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("ContainsAtLeastOneDigit", function (value) { 
        return /^[a-z]+[0-9]/i.test(value); 
}, 'Your input must contain at least 1 letter and 1 number');
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you’re doing this validation on passwords to try to make them more secure, it would be better to do a more direct check of the security of a password with the [`zxcvbn` library](https://github.com/lowe/zxcvbn). A phrase like `release to the Department of` is more secure than `password1`, though it doesn’t pass your validation.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. That's a useful link. Thankfully in this case it's just a text field and not a password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A JavaScript regex to match text with at least 1 letter and 1 number:

```
/[a-z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[a-z]/i
```

It checks that the text contains either a letter `[a-z]` and then a number `[0-9]`, with other characters `.*` optionally in between, or `|` a number and then a letter, with other characters optionally in between.

[Live demo of the regex](https://regex101.com/r/Ttcoad/3)

Comment: Fantastic. That worked like a dream. Big thanks. I'll accept your answer as soon as stack allows me to. Thanks again.